# Why i can't create this table on MYSQL Workbench? (Error on Constraint)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I was trying to create a table on my MySQL-Workbench, but, everytime i try to execute this line under me, the code didn't execute. It's say that is a "Error Code : 3813 Column check constraint 'lancamento_chk_2' references other column".

```
create table lancamento
    (
    id bigint not null primary key auto_increment,
    descricao varchar(100) not null,
    mes integer not null,
    ano integer not null, 
    valor numeric (16,2) not null,
    tipo varchar(20) check( tipo in('RECEITA','DESPESA')) not null,
    status_lanca varchar(20) check(tipo in ('PENDENTE','CANCELADO','EFETIVADO')) NOT NULL,
    id_usuario bigint references usuarios(id) ,
    data_cad_lanca date
    );
```

Comment: `status_lanca varchar(20) check(tipo in ('PENDENTE','CANCELADO','EFETIVADO')) NOT NULL,`, don't you mean to check "status_lanca" here ? not "tipo".

Comment: status_lanca varchar(20) check(tipo in  looks odd should it not be status_lanca varchar(20) check(status_lanca in ?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggest, you have a `check` constraint during column definition that is checking another column than itself. This is not valid in MySQL.

And since the name is lancamento_chk_2, it means this is about hte 2nd `check` in your table, therefore it's the line about `status_lanca` column, I guess the correct one should be:

```sql
status_lanca varchar(20) check(status_lanca in ('PENDENTE','CANCELADO','EFETIVADO')) NOT NULL,
```

(instead of `check(tipo in...`).

I'm guessing the error is actually the column name, since you are already checking that `tipo` is something else on the line above.

If you actually do want to create a check involving multiple columns, in this case you need to add an [explicit constraint](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-check-constraint/) after the columns list.